# Who supports WTAI (Wireless Telephony Application Interface)

Tags: mobile, wtai

Does anyone know how widely WTAI is supported in mobile phones, or can point to a list of supported devices.

Answer (score 1):

The great majority of device support some WTAI primitives (because they are include in WAP). Those are current supported: WTAPublic.makeCall, WTAPublic.sendDTMF and WTAPublic.addPBEntry

More information [here](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showpost.php?p=9463&postcount=2) and [here](http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/1673.html).

Answer (score 0):

I came across a couple resources on device capabilities today.

[DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com)
and
[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are hoping to use WTAPI for.

If it is for a wap site then check out Device Atlas or WURFL, or Mobile elements

The next problem that we have is after you have the click to call link, you need to track it we have done this in the past using a service like OnSip.

Whereby each call goes to OnSip then they forward the call onto the correct number they then call to a url hosted on our servers whenever a call comes through enabling us to track the number of people who clicked on the click to call link